# Check if all points in a set lie on the same line

Tags: python, geometry

I'm given a list with coordinates of n points, let's say:

```
points = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

And I need to check if all of them lie on the same line. I also decided to consider 3 cases to avoid dividing by zero when x1 == x2.
So here's my code in Python:

```
# 2 points always lie on a line
if n <= 2:
    print("yes")
else:
    # leave only unique points
    points = list(set(points))
    x1, y1 = points[0]
    x2, y2 = points[1]

    # if two points have the same x coordinate
    # then they lie on a vertical line and
    # all other points have to have the same x coordinate too
    if x2 == x1:
        for i in range(2, len(points)):
            if points[i][0] != x1:
                print("no")
                break
        else: print("yes")

    # same with a horizontal line
    elif y2 == y1:
        for i in range(2, len(points)):
            if points[i][1] != y1:
                print("no")
                break
        else: print("yes")

    else:
        a = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
        b = y2 - a * x2

        for i in range(2, len(points)):
            x, y = points[i]
            if (y != a * x + b):
                print("no")
                break
        else: print("yes")
```

It seems that I have a mistake somewhere in the code but I don't really understand what it is.

Comment: How does that mistake manifest itself ? What is not working?

Comment: If it's not working, then either (a) you have some points on a line that it says are not, or (b) you have some points not on a line that it says are.  Construct a minimal failing case, then find the path in your code you wanted it to take, and determine why it didn't.

Comment: Also, you are going to have problems with the divides you're doing, which are going to force the values to be floats and you will then have inexact numbers.  If the points are integers, then you *must* keep them as integers.  If they can be float, then you need to incorporate a margin for error (which will make it a bit ugly).

Comment: Note you don't need to treat the `y2 == y1` case separately from the general case.

Comment: To keep them as integers, rather than checking if `a/b == c/d`, instead check if `a*d == b*c`, which is mathematically equivalent but will avoid converting integers to floats.

Comment: Or use the Fractions module

Comment: @mlotz it's a homework so I only get an error saying that the answer for one of the tests is wrong :) That's a reason I don't see where I'm wrong exactly

Comment: @TomKarzes in an input list all the coordinates are integers. Thank you for the idea of changing `a/b == c/d`, I'll try that!

Comment: Then solve it by hand and figure out which part of the answer produced by your code is wrong. You really are supposed to reduce the problematic code to a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Using cross product of vectors eliminates the complexity of having to deal with special cases where division by zero might happen. Three points are collinear if the cross product of the vectors formed by the two vectors defined by the 3 points is equal to zero:

```
import math

class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

class Vector:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def cross(self, other):
        return self.x * other.y - self.y * other.x

def are_collinear(three_points):
    a, b, c = three_points  
    # better use math.isclose than == to check for floats
    return math.isclose((b-a).cross(c-a), 0.0)

points = [Point(1, 2), Point(2, 3), Point(3, 4)]
print(are_collinear(points))
# True


points = [Point(1, 2), Point(3, 3), Point(3, 4)]
print(are_collinear(points))
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

From any point in the list (e.g. first one) if all other points have the same slope with that one, then they are on the same line.

```
def sameLine(points):
    x0,y0  = points[0]
    points = [ (x,y) for x,y in points if x != x0 or y != y0 ]      # Other points
    slopes = [ (y-y0)/(x-x0) if x!=x0 else None for x,y in points ] # None for vertical Line
    return all( s == slopes[0] for s in slopes)
```